# how to pass variable from callback function to function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, johnny-five

Here i am sending sensor data to database using simple javascript (johnny five)
using this code

```
var five = require("johnny-five");
var pg = require("pg");
var conString = "pg://admin:raja@localhost:5432/data";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

function call(n)
{
  client.connect();
  client.query("INSERT INTO sensordata (event) VALUES (n);");
}


var board = new five.Board();
board.on("ready", function() {

  var sensor = new five.Sensor.Digital(2);

  sensor.on("change", function() {
    var n = this.value;
    call(n);
  });
});
```

My question is can i pass the streaming data variable n in the sensor call back function to call method.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's a "streaming data variable"? Also, according to [the Johnny-Five docs](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Sensor), `value` is not a function.

Comment: Sensor data to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you're looking here is a simple query templating, supported by all sql clients:

```
client.query("INSERT INTO sensordata (event) VALUES ($1);", n);
```

This way you'll be able to pass the value of `n` variable to your SQL query.

**Update:** And you don't have to call `client.connect()` before every call to `client.query`. You should only call it once to establish DB connection, after that `pg.Client` will use it to send all subsequent requests.